# Getting all items less than a month old

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is there a way to get all objects with a date less than a month ago in django.

Something like:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(less than a month old).order_by(...)
```

Comment: What do you mean "all objects"? Do you mean all objects of a particular type?

Comment: Yeah, all objects of type "Item"

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What is your definition of a "month"? 30 days? 31 days? Past that, this should do it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
items = Item.objects.filter(my_date__gte=last_month).order_by(...)
```

Takes advantange of the [gte](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gte) field lookup.

Comment: This fails when datetime.today() is March 1st - last month was February, not January.

If you don't need it be exact, this will work fine (30 days ago = last month) but if you do actually need to know what happened last month, there isn't an easy way to go about it in python (AFAIK).

Comment: there is *relatiedelta* in **python-dateutil** which can give you exact past month.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725093/209050)'s one way to get the previous month using nothing but `datetime`.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def is_leap_year(year): 
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return year % 100 == 0

    return year % 4 == 0

def get_lapse():
    last_month = datetime.today().month
    current_year = datetime.today().year

    #is last month a month with 30 days?
    if last_month in [9, 4, 6, 11]:
        lapse = 30

    #is last month a month with 31 days?
    elif last_month in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]:
        lapse = 31

    #is last month February?
    else:
        if is_leap_year(current_year):
            lapse = 29
        else:
            lapse = 30

    return lapse

last_month_filter = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=get_lapse())

items = Item.objects.filter(date_created__gte=last_month_filter)
```

This will cater for all cases I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = Item.objects.filter(created_date__gte=aMonthAgo)
```

Where aMonthAgo would be calculated by datetime and timedelta.

Comment: perhaps will be nice if you add how to calculate aMonthAgo