# python date of the previous month

Tags: python, date, time

I am trying to get the date of the previous month with python.
Here is what i've tried:

```
str( time.strftime('%Y') ) + str( int(time.strftime('%m'))-1 )
```

However, this way is bad for 2 reasons: First it returns 20122 for the February of 2012 (instead of 201202) and secondly it will return 0 instead of 12 on January.

I have solved this trouble in bash with

```
echo $(date -d"3 month ago" "+%G%m%d")
```

I think that if bash has a built-in way for this purpose, then python, much more equipped, should provide something better than forcing writing one's own script to achieve this goal. Of course i could do something like:

```
if int(time.strftime('%m')) == 1:
    return '12'
else:
    if int(time.strftime('%m')) < 10:
        return '0'+str(time.strftime('%m')-1)
    else:
        return str(time.strftime('%m') -1)
```

I have not tested this code and i don't want to use it anyway (unless I can't find any other way:/)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: related: [What's the simplest way to subtract a month from a date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7153449/4279)

Comment: Note that AFAIK only the GNU CoreUtils version of `date` supports the `-d` flag as used in your bash solution

Answer (score 487, accepted):

[datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) and the datetime.timedelta classes are your friend.

1. find today.
2. use that to find the first day of this month.
3. use timedelta to backup a single day, to the last day of the previous month.
4. print the YYYYMM string you're looking for.

Like this:

```py
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
last_month = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print(last_month.strftime("%Y%m"))
```

`201202` is printed.

Comment: you could use `.replace()` method: `datetime.utcnow().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Cool! I missed the replace method.

Comment: You can also chain the `.replace()` function. Do it once to get the last month, then do it again to get the day you want. First: `d = date.today()`  then `one_month_ago = (d.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=d.day)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are correct -- thanks for pointing that out. There doesn't seem to be an elegant one-liner for this as a "month" is not a constant time period. You can do something ugly by importing `calendar` and using `calendar.mdays[d.month-1]` and more ugliness in a `min()` function in the 2nd `replace`, but it seems un-Pythonic and doesn't account for corner cases. I've updated my answer below using `try - except` which accounts for all cases, although a I hate using exceptions as part of an algorithm.

Comment: see the answer of Ivan, and add: min(date.today().day, last_day_of_previous_month.day)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! This is the shortest method that is the safest and all around sexy. Kudos my friend.

Comment: `firstOfThisMonth = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)`
`firstOfLastMonth = (firstOfThisMonth - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m")+"-01"`

Comment: This does not work well on all edge cases. The `dateutil.relativedata` does.

Answer (score 123):

You should use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).
With that, you can use relativedelta, it's an improved version of timedelta.

```
>>> import datetime 
>>> import dateutil.relativedelta
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print now
2012-03-15 12:33:04.281248
>>> print now + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1)
2012-02-15 12:33:04.281248
```

Comment: It's not working for the first month of year:
>>> IllegalMonthError: bad month number -1; must be 1-12

Comment: @mtoloo What version of dateutil? I am not having that issue, but I will add some alternative syntax

Comment: I prefer this one because while @bgporter has a very nice solution, his one doesn't work as nice for looking up the next month.

Comment: @mtoloo You've probably mistyped months/month

Comment: @r_black Yes You are right. That was my fault. Solution given here is correct and no further check is needed for the first month of the year.

Comment: I had the same problem with @mtoloo, fixed by substracting (-) relativedelta as months=1

Comment: Note that if the previous month's date doesn't exist (e.g. October 31st exists, but September 31st does not exist), then relativedelta will use the next older day (e.g. September 30th)

Answer (score 58):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

first_day_of_current_month = date.today().replace(day=1)
last_day_of_previous_month = first_day_of_current_month - timedelta(days=1)

print "Previous month:", last_day_of_previous_month.month
```

Or:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

prev = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
print prev.month
```

Comment: part of the solution... to find the day of last month, add something like this: day_previous_month = min(today.day, last_day_of_previous_month.day) to avoid exceeding the number of days.

Comment: #one line formated to YYYYMM 'from datetime import date, timedelta
ANOMES = (date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m")'

Answer (score 32):

For someone who got here and looking to get both the first and last day of the previous month:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

last_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)

start_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=last_day_of_prev_month.day)

# For printing results
print("First day of prev month:", start_day_of_prev_month)
print("Last day of prev month:", last_day_of_prev_month)
```

Output:

```
First day of prev month: 2019-02-01
Last day of prev month: 2019-02-28
```

Comment: If you want to get the start and end of a month (and more), have a look at the `Calendar` module: https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-the-python-calendar-module/

Comment: If we want 2nd previous month start and end ?

Comment: You are a saviour! I was fiddling with calendar, dateutil with my soggy brain. But this is much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

**Simple, one liner:**

```
import datetime as dt
previous_month = (dt.date.today().replace(day=1) - dt.timedelta(days=1)).month
```

Answer (score 10):

Its very easy and simple. Do this

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

today_date = datetime.today()
print "todays date time: %s" %today_date

one_month_ago = today_date - relativedelta(months=1)
print "one month ago date time: %s" % one_month_ago
print "one month ago date: %s" % one_month_ago.date()
```

Here is the output:
$python2.7 main.py

```
todays date time: 2016-09-06 02:13:01.937121
one month ago date time: 2016-08-06 02:13:01.937121
one month ago date: 2016-08-06
```

Answer (score 9):

Building on [bgporter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725093/564514).

```
def prev_month_range(when = None): 
    """Return (previous month's start date, previous month's end date)."""
    if not when:
        # Default to today.
        when = datetime.datetime.today()
    # Find previous month: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9725093/564514
    # Find today.
    first = datetime.date(day=1, month=when.month, year=when.year)
    # Use that to find the first day of this month.
    prev_month_end = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_month_start = datetime.date(day=1, month= prev_month_end.month, year= prev_month_end.year)
    # Return previous month's start and end dates in YY-MM-DD format.
    return (prev_month_start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), prev_month_end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 6):

With the [Pendulum](https://pypi.org/project/pendulum/) very complete library, we have the `subtract` method (and not "subStract"):

```
import pendulum
today = pendulum.datetime.today()  # 2020, january
lastmonth = today.subtract(months=1)
lastmonth.strftime('%Y%m')
# '201912'
```

We see that it handles jumping years.

The reverse equivalent is `add`.

https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#addition-and-subtraction

Answer (score 3):

```
def prev_month(date=datetime.datetime.today()):
    if date.month == 1:
        return date.replace(month=12,year=date.year-1)
    else:
        try:
            return date.replace(month=date.month-1)
        except ValueError:
            return prev_month(date=date.replace(day=date.day-1))
```

Comment: Breaks on March 31st

Answer (score 3):

Explicit way:

```
import datetime
result = (datetime.datetime.today().month - 2) % 12 + 1
```

The problem is how to transfer `month` [1, 2, 3, ..., 12] to [12, 1, 2, ..., 11].

Step1: `month = month - 1` transfer [1, 2, 3, ..., 12] to [0, 1, 2, ..., 11].

Step2: `month = (month - 1) % 12` transfer [0, 1, 2, ..., 11] to [11, 0, 1, ..., 10].

Step3: `month = month + 1` transfer [11, 0, 1, ..., 10] to [12, 1, 2, ..., 11].

So, the result is `result = (month - 2) % 12 + 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, timezone

current_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
last_day_previous_month = datetime.combine(current_time.replace(day=1), time.max) - timedelta(days=1)
first_day_previous_month = datetime.combine(last_day_previous_month, time.min).replace(day=1)
```

**Output:**

```
first_day_previous_month: 2022-02-01 00:00:00 
last_day_previous_month: 2022-02-28 23:59:59.999999
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a pure math answer using divmod. Pretty inneficient because of the multiplication, could do just as well a simple check on the number of month (if equal to 12, increase year, etc)

```
year = today.year
month = today.month

nm = list(divmod(year * 12 + month + 1, 12))
if nm[1] == 0:
    nm[1] = 12
    nm[0] -= 1
pm = list(divmod(year * 12 + month - 1, 12))
if pm[1] == 0:
    pm[1] = 12
    pm[0] -= 1

next_month = nm
previous_month = pm
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a high level library [`dateparser`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser) that can determine the past date given natural language, and return the corresponding Python `datetime` object

```
from dateparser import parse
parse('4 months ago')
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have come here because you're working with **Jython in NiFi**. This is how I ended up implementing it. I deviated a little from [this answer by Robin Carlo Catacutan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55295829/156144) because accessing last_day_of_prev_month.day wasn't possible due to a Jython datatype issue explained [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NiFi-java-lang-NullPointerException-when-reading-csv-file/m-p/269871/highlight/true#M207141) that for some reason seems to exist in NiFi'S Jython but not in vanilla Jython.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import calendar
    
flowFile = session.get()
    
if flowFile != None:

    first_weekday_in_prev_month, num_days_in_prev_month = calendar.monthrange(date.today().year,date.today().month-1)

    last_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
    first_day_of_prev_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=num_days_in_prev_month)
            
    last_day_of_prev_month = str(last_day_of_prev_month)
    first_day_of_prev_month = str(first_day_of_prev_month)
    
    flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, {
        "last_day_of_prev_month": last_day_of_prev_month,
        "first_day_of_prev_month": first_day_of_prev_month
    })
    
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off the comment of @J.F. Sebastian, you can chain the `replace()` function to go back one "month". Since a month is not a constant time period, this solution tries to go back to the same date the previous month, which of course does not work for all months. In such a case, this algorithm defaults to the last day of the prior month.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime(2012, 3, 31) # A problem date as an example

# last day of last month
one_month_ago = (d.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1))
try:
    # try to go back to same day last month
    one_month_ago = one_month_ago.replace(day=d.day)
except ValueError:
    pass
print("one_month_ago: {0}".format(one_month_ago))
```

Output:

```
one_month_ago: 2012-02-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta    
last_month = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=32)).strftime("%Y%m")
```

Comment: how does it make sure its last month date only ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Months(0-12) (1 for Previous month)

#last day of (n) previous month (n=months)
day = datetime(2023, 1, 13)
n = 1
lastDayMonth = ((day - relativedelta(months=n) + relativedelta(day=31)).date());

#First day of previous month (n=months=1)
firstDayMonth = ((day - relativedelta(months=n) + relativedelta(day=1)).date());

print("Last Day of Month - "+ str(lastDayMonth))
print("First Day of Month - "+ str(firstDayMonth))

#Last business day (Friday) of prev (n) month if last day on weekend
lastBusDay = (lastDayMonth - timedelta(max(1,(lastDayMonth.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))) if lastDayMonth.weekday() in (5,6) else lastDayMonth

print("Last Business Day of Month - " + str(lastBusinessDay))

print()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more easier to use the timedelta module from datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
lastmonth_date = now - timedelta(days=now.day)
```

Now, to get last month's number you can use:

```
lastmonth = lastmonth_date.strftime("%m")
```

To get the year,

```
lastmonth_year = lastmonth_date.strftime("%Y")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

lastmonth = int(pd.to_datetime("today").strftime("%Y%m"))-1

print(lastmonth)
```

> 202101

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
YYYYMM = (date.today().replace(day=1)-timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for January of each year: (202201 - 1) = 202200!!!