# entering a date programatically in python sql string

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

this is my current query

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT *'\
    'FROM students' \
    'WHERE numberofclasses > 4')
list = cursor.fetchall()
```

now I wish to add to the string:

1. that `registrationdate` was in the past month --> how do I calculate and add the result to the string
2. the name starts with 'l' --> how do i add `name like '%l'` into the above string

**Note:**

1. it's important for my question to keep the string format of `'...'\ '...'\` and not write it in between `''' ... '''`
2. this is an example for a much complicated query that must be executed this way and not through Django ORM platform.

Comment: I guess this is a simplified version of the query you'd like to execute, but if it is not: than just use the query managers as present within Django. This would safe you lots of trouble. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: @WouterKleinHeerenbrink edited my question, (note 2) the query i need to run is too complicated for django

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it up in few questions:

1. How to determine 'past month'
   [python date of the previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724906/python-date-of-the-previous-month)
2. Format for your database depends on the backend your using
   Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html
   Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html
3. Entering the value in your string:

Your could concatenate a formatted date:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT *'\
    'FROM students' \
    'WHERE numberofclasses > 4' \
    'AND mydate > \'%s\'', [month_ago.isoformat()])
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat

I do not understand your second question, for this seems to contain the answer already.

Comment: the embedding of  `month_ago.isoformat()` raises the error of: `operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= integer` I think I need to add the **'** before and after the date in c language it will be like this `\'` but in python it doesn't work

Comment: you're right, I forgot the quotes so Postgres will see this as an integer. The escaping in Python is equal to C, `\'`. If for some reason this does not work you could go for double quotes of course. I also changed the way to insert arguments following https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw