# How get name of prev months short from or full form numbers in python/Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-datetime

Forgive me If i'm asking a very stupid questions.

I'm trying to get name of the past months instead of numbers my django framework:

Example: For instance, if I have `12`, I want to return `december or dec`

Right now, I had this external python scripts that sort the day, weeks, month and years.

Here the codes for external scripts Name;**basicfun**: (only on the months)

```
#basicfun codes (external python scripts)  

 def selectDates(query):

    if query == 'Previous-Months':
    dataset = datetime.now().month - 1
    dataset.strftime("%b")

 return dataset
```

It will return to my django view to use as a filter for Queryset

Here the Frame works codes on view:

```
#Django view 
       def ph(request):
            query = request.GET.get('dateRange')
            fill = selectDates(query)
            data = tank_system.objects.all().filter(datetime__contains=fill)
            return render(request, 'FrounterWeb/extends/ph.html', {'tank': data})
```

## Solution I had try

This link:
[Get month name from number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557553/get-month-name-from-number)

1.

```
   dataset = datetime.now().month - 1
   dataset.strftime("%b")
```

error:

```
Exception Type:AttributeError
Exception Value:'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is because `datetime.now().month` is an integer. `strftime` is a method on the `datetime` object.

You can get the current month by doing:

`month = datetime.now().strftime("%b")`

To get previous month names, easy but sort of "hacky" way to do this would be to just create a dictionary of the month strings you want with the month number as keys:

```
from datetime import datetime

def limit_month_number(start_month, months_ago):
    """
    This function will return a value from 1-12 inclusive.
    >>> limit_month_number(1,3) -> 10
    >>> limit_month_number(12,14) -> 10
    """
    month_number = start_month - (months_ago % 12)
    if month_number < 1:
        month_number = 12 + month_number 
    return month_number

def get_prev_month(months_ago):
    months = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}

    this_month = datetime.now().month

    month_number = limit_month_number(this_month, months_ago)

    prev_month = months[month_number]
    return prev_month

print(get_prev_month(2)) # 'Nov', two months ago from now
```

Also, I must point out that you can do this using `datetime`. Check out this other post: [python date of the previous month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724906/python-date-of-the-previous-month)

Comment: thank you Kevin it work on the current month, as the previous month as you said is really hacky

Comment: The benefit of using your own dictionary is that you have the choice of using the abbreviation or the full name of the month.

Comment: I didn't get last month but this months instead, I wonder is becuase the turn didn't work?

Comment: I made an edit to the code. Try that out. I will let you fill in the other 7 months yourself.

Comment: @KevinWelch You can reduce the 'hackiness' by using the standard library's [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module to provide the month names - see the `month_name` and `month_abbr` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html).

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = dt.date.today()  # 2019-01-03
>>> (today - relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%B')  # `%b' for abbreviated month
'December'
```

For the last three months, you could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [(dt.date.today() - relativedelta(months=x)).strftime('%B') for x in range(3, 0, -1)]
['October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: Do you need to install relativedlta? becuase  #from detutil.relativedelta import relativedelta# Django do not reconsider

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
previous_month = (datetime.date.today().replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%B')
```