# Print date of 1 month ago python

Tags: python, datetime, variables, formatdatetime

The problem:

I am trying to print out the date from a month ago. So instead of the result being:

```
>>> 2021-03-12
```

It will be in this instead

```
>>> 2021-02-12
```

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import date
import datetime
from email.utils import formatdate

now = formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=True)
tday = date.today()

print(tday)
```

I have seen tons of different examples but all of them change the format of the date structure that I already have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724906/python-date-of-the-previous-month

Comment: What do you want for one month earlier than March 31, 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to @chess_lover_6

```
from datetime import datetime 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta 

now = datetime.now()
last_month_date = now + relativedelta(months=-1)
last_month_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

You will get `2021-02-12`

Comment: This worked! I had to make the last line a variable like this `lm = last_month_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` then `print(lm)` but that totally worked for me!!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta 

now = datetime.now()
last_month_date = now + relativedelta(months=-1)
last_month_date=last_month_date.split(" ")[0]
```

Use dateutil as it has a improved delta

Comment: This isn't the same format as what I need. 
I need `2021-02-12` and your script is giving me the time as well which I don't need `2021-02-12 17:31:09.836329`. Is there anyway to just have ` 2021-02-12`?

Comment: The default format is ISO down to the fraction of a second. You can modify that with the `.isoformat()` method, but only down to hours, if you want only days then convert it to a date as in `last_month_date.date()`.

Comment: @JohnBayko thanks for that explaination as that helps me to understand why the format's default is that way. I will mark this in my notes for the future so I can use this. (And trust me I will be using this.) Thanks again John.