# How to see if user joined server over a month ago

Tags: python, datetime, time, discord

I have a user's server join date, I want to see if their join date is over a month ago. If it is, continue.

```py
today = datetime.datetime.now()
lastMonth = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
if user.joined_at > lastMonth:
    print(user.joined_at)
```

The error it gives me.

```
if user.joined_at > lastMonth:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`
```

Comment: How would I subtract? @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Python, forgot to add Tag @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Good luck......

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724906/python-date-of-the-previous-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by a month you mean 30 days, then you can do something like that:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
one_month_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=30)

if now - time_to_check > one_month_delta:
    # A month has passed
```

If you want to test if a calendar month has passed, then you would have to do a little more work and take into consideration that not all months contain the same amount of days...

Comment: I just saw your edit. In your case, you need to replace `time_to_check` with `user.joined_at`

Comment: Also, if `user.joined_at` is a utc time, then the above should work fine. If it's not, you need to use `datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.utcnow()`