# Filtering objects less than 30 days and excluding object's user for a particular object

Tags: django

I have 2 models called Car and Review . A user can write many reviews for a car.
I am able to filter all the reviews for a certain car . 
The issue i'm facing  is , I only want to filter all the reviews that belong to a particular car in less than 30 days and excluding the user who own the car.

This question support my question [Getting all items less than a month old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979533/getting-all-items-less-than-a-month-old) but I am unable 
to filter all the reviews that belong to a particular car in less than 30 days and excluding the user who own the car.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)


class Review(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    review = models.TextField()
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

*Filter all the review for a particular car*

```
Car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
Review = Review.objects.filter(car=Car)
```

*Filter all the review for a particular car but it retrieves all the reviews for everycar in 30 days which I don't want . I want to retrieve only the reviews in less than 30 days for a particular car and excluding the user who own the car*

```
Car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
Review = Review.objects.filter(car__in=car,review__gte=month)
```

My question is How can I filter all the reviews for a particular car in less than 30 days and not including the reviews of the user who own the car .

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to filter on `created` field rather than on `review` field to lookup older entries:

```
from django.db import Q
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)

# filtering step by step to give better understanding
reviews = Review.objects.filter(car__id=car.id) # filter by car first
reviews = reviews.filter(created__gte=threshold) # filter by datetime
reviews = reviews.filter(~Q(user__id=car.user.id)) # exclude user reviews who owns the car

# filtering in single step
reviews = Review.objects.filter(
    ~Q(user__id=car.user.id), car__id=car.id, created__gte=threshold)
```

Comment: `Review` is your model name. Make sure you are not overriding this accidently. As you were doing here `Review = Review.objects.filter(car=Car)`

Comment: Okay , I don't understand this error SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg (<console>, line 1)
>>> WOW =Review.objects.filter(car__id=car.id,~Q(user__id=car.user.id))

Comment: sorry my bad I have updated single step query `~Q(user__id=car.user.id)` should comes first in filter.

Comment: I also understand why it gave me that error , haha . Thank you Aamir

Comment: Aamir , Could you help me on this question if you have time please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625690/validating-email-as-username-when-logging-in-forms-py-error

Answer (score 1):

How about following the relationship 'backwards' (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) :

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
car = Car.objects.get(pk=1)
reviews = car.review_set.exclude(user=car.user).filter(created__gt=threshold)
```