# Authenticate user using email and password

Tags: django

I have a form that only allow users to login via username . I decided to only allow user to login via email instead of username.

First, this is not a duplication of any question relating to logging via email because in my scenario, I validate and authenticate the user in `forms.py` before he proceed to the final login in views so it give me the chance to raise an error for incorrect login passwords etc.

The issue i'm facing is I modified my `forms.py` to raise an error if the email doesn't exist which works but It wouldn't let the user login via his email.

```
 def LoginRequest(request):
     form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)    
     if request.POST and form.is_valid():
         user = form.login(request)
         if user:
             login(request, user)
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Hello'))

     return render(request, 'login.html',{'form': form})
```

This is my original code which only allow users to login via username

```
 class LoginForm(forms.Form):
     username = forms.CharField()
     password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

     def clean(self):        
         username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         if not user or not user.is_active:
             raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid. Please try again.")
         return self.cleaned_data

     def login(self, request):
         username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         return user
```

This is my modified code which only allow users to login via email. I thought a lot about how I would do it  but this is the best idea I came up with. Sorry it's a bit confusing.
The problem is, it wouldn't let the user login. I don't understand why.

```
 class LoginForm(forms.Form):
     username = forms.CharField()
     password = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

     def clean(self):       
         user = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

         if User.objects.filter(email=user).exists():
             password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
             user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
             if not user or not user.is_active:
                 raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid. Please try again.")
             return self.cleaned_data

     def login(self, request):
         username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
         password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
         return user
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `dougis` pointed out you are trying to authenticate the user using email, But `authenticate` function authenticates user based on username and password. So here is the trick to authenticate the user using email (complete working form):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

    def clean(self):
        user = self.authenticate_via_email()
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid. Please try again.")
        else:
            self.user = user
        return self.cleaned_data

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return authenticate(
            username=self.user.username,
            password=self.cleaned_data['password'])

    def authenticate_via_email(self):
        """
            Authenticate user using email.
            Returns user object if authenticated else None
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if email:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
                if user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
                    return user
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        return None
```

views.py

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        user = form.authenticate_user()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Hello'))

    return render(request, 'login.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: @JackRoster i have updated my answer and provided complete working example. Thanks

Comment: No problem. If that helps you thats only matter to me :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also write a custom backend:

```
# yourapp.backends.py    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class EmailOrUsernameModelBackend(object):
    """ Authenticate user by username or email """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        if '@' in username:
            kwargs = {'email': username}
        else:
            kwargs = {'username': username}
        try:

            user = User.objects.get(**kwargs)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id=None):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Now add your backend to settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'yourapp.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are testing against 2 different fields.
You look for the user against email

```
if User.objects.filter(email=user).exists():
```

but then validate against username

```
user = authenticate(username=user, password=password)
```

If you are using the email address the auth line should be

```
user = authenticate(email=user, password=password)
```

Comment: it doesn't let you authenticate via email

Comment: Thanks,
I was simply looking at the code itself (no real knowledge of the back end he is using but it jumped right out that the compare was different). Hopefully someday I will have enough points to actually make comments instead of needing to answer :-)